# Convert OracleLob to String C#

Tags: c#, string, oracle

Does anyone know how convert the `OracleLob` Value in string? `ToString()` only returns the name of the class: `System.Data.OracleClient.OracleLob`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure it's actually characters (CLob or NCLob), then you can use the [Value property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.oracleclient.oraclelob.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Please consider using the [Oracle driver](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html) to connect to Oracle, the Microsoft driver is just for backwards compatibility. Microsoft announced years ago, that using the Oracle driver would be the best way to connect to Oracle databases.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need: [OracleLob.Value Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oraclelob.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

*For Blob data types, Value returns the entire underlying data as a contiguous array of type Byte[]. For Clob and NClob data types, Value returns all the data as a String data type. For null data, Value returns DBNull. By comparing the returned values, you can distinguish among empty data, null data, and data.*